# Is there a name for this particular class of topological space?

Tags: general-topology, geometry, differential-geometry, differential-topology, manifolds

This is a simple question, but I can't figure out the name for this class of topological space.

Say you start with the affine space $\mathbb{R}^n$ for finite n, and equip it with a metric.

Now, say you impose the equivalence relation generated by the relation such that for any two points $p, q$, $p \sim q \iff p-q \in V$, where V is a set of linearly independent vectors and $|V| \leq n$. This gives you a new topological space which can be thought of as a topological quotient space of the original (or also thought of as an orbit space). I will notate this space $\mathbb{R}^n/V$, and note that this new space also naturally inherits a metric from the old one via the quotient metric.

- Example: if you start with $\mathbb{R}^2$ and do this with $|V|$ = 1, you end up with the cylinder, and if you do it with $|V|$ = 2, you end up with the flat torus.

Consider the set of all spaces one can obtain in this way; by starting with some finite-dimensional $\mathbb{R}^n$ and modding by some set of vectors $V$. Is there a name for this particular class of metric space? It seems like this would be a subset of the set of "Finsler manifolds," but I don't know if there's anything more specific than that.

Also, if it makes this question easier to answer, you can ignore the metric and just focus on the particular set of topological spaces that are constructible in this way; does this set have a name?

EDIT: as mentioned, this is the same as the set of all spaces one can generate by $\mathbb{R}^a \times T^b$. Do these spaces have any sort of canonical name? They're one way to generalize a cylinder, but not the only way.

Comment: If I am not mistaken the relation $\sim$ you defined above is not an equivalence relation. In fact it is neither reflexive ($0 \not\in V$) nor symmetric ($v \in V$ implies $-v \not\in V$) nor transitive. Maybe you mean something different or I do not understand it correctly.

Comment: Usually one takes the generated equivalence relation.

Comment: Yes, what Martin said. I've cleaned it up to make it explicit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your notion is equivalent to the following: Start with your subset $V$ and generate the additive subgroup $\Gamma< R^n$ by this subset. Now, form the quotient $R^n/\Gamma$ as in the theory of covering spaces: You identify points $p, q\in R^n$ whenever there exists $\gamma\in \Gamma$ sending $p$ to $q$. The quotient space is diffeomorphic to $M=R^{n-k} \times T^{k}$, where $k$ is the rank of the free abelian group $\Gamma$, $T^k$ is the $k$-dimensional torus. Note that $\Gamma$ is the group of automorphisms of the covering map $R^n\to M$. I am not sure there is a standard name for such spaces. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_manifold for references.

Comment: Nice answer, I was thinking in the same lines. What I still do not understand, why can we assume $\mathbb{R}^n$ to have to natural topology?

Comment: Euclidean manifold with trivial holonomy group would be one term to uniquely identify this class of manifolds.

Comment: @MatthiasKlupsch: When reading the question I was assuming that you mean the standard topology on $R^n$. If there is another topology you have in mind, you should specify it. An algebraic geometer would equip it with Zariski topology (this is the only other natural topology on $R^n$ I know), but they typically are not interested in questions of this nature.

Comment: Yeah, I meant the Euclidean topology.

Comment: studiosus, thanks for your answer - I saw the same result, but I guess there wasn't a name for it. Also, you mention the result that any quotient space obtainable in this way is diffeomorphic to the product of a hypertorus and a flat space, but the converse is also true, right? That is, a topological space is constructible using the method described iff it is the product of $R^{n-k} \times T^k$.

Comment: @MikeBattaglia: Yes, it is if and only if.